# Good icon for the word "practice"?

Tags: android, icons, material-design

I am creating a sports app where the users can track their practice for a specific aspect of the game. In my menu, I'd like an icon next to it to convey its meaning (and I have an icon for every other entry in the menu).

Right now I am using the Material Icon from Google ["border color"](https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_border_color). I chose this because that function of the app creates a new entry for their practice stats. I'd rather have something that signifies the action of practicing rather than the function of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no (wide-spread) specific symbol for practice or training, at least not for self-practice. There's something for training/schooling, but I don't think that's what you're looking for:

[image]  [image]
<sub>(source: [epiloguesystems.com](http://dev.epiloguesystems.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Icon-Training-128.png))</sub>

---

In this context I'd focus more on the tracking aspect, i.e. progress, which can be shown with graphs and charts, so you  could use those as a symbol in the menu:

[image] [image] [image]

---

If you strongly want something that specifically mentions repeated actions and improvement, you could try making your own icon by combining symbols for those. For example circular arrows plus a shooting target:

[image]

But something like that, combining two ideas in one icon, quickly becomes cluttered and confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option isn't to use an icon at all, especially for such an ambiguous option.  Your clearest option for the user is to actually use the word `Practice`.  There is no icon that's universal in even the slightest sense that would symbolize "practice" to your users.

Icons should only be used when there is a universal understanding behind them, and believe me, there are **far** less of these symbols than people realize and *unfortunately* use in websites and apps.